# What does the y-axis graph of the FPS counter of Google Chrome depict?

Tags: google-chrome, fps

I hope this question isnt too obscure. I enabled the fps counter through chrome://flags. It gives the fps and a graph of the fps to the left. What is the horizontal graph to the right and the number above it in this picture: (4-63)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a histogram of graph data

> I aligned the histogram right beside the graph so both make use of the same y-axis and the data explains itself (hopefully).
>   I'm not sure if I treat the numbers the best way, I just put the measured fps values into buckets, so far.

From here

> https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-dev/_GOLojYXc3s/vwlkjCsnILAJ

Comment: Good link! What would the histogram show? The link doesnt specify that

Comment: The histograms represent the distribution of average Frames per Second.